# Simple for loop in django view which creates a pdf file

Tags: python, django, django-views, reportlab

It seems to be a very easy problem but I can not manage it :(

I have a view which should create for me a pdf file. I need there a loop and I don't know why it doesn't work. I need to print all of list's questions.
I have checked and I have 3 questions in "pytanie" list but my loop print me only one question (last question)

```
for i in range(len(pytanie)):
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)
    p.drawString(10, 800, ' '+ pytanie[i].title)
```

The whole code in this view

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from django.http import HttpResponse
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing 
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.qr import QrCodeWidget 
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from pytania.models import Pytanie


def test_qr(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="egzamin.pdf"'

    pytanie = Pytanie.objects.all()

    for i in range(len(pytanie)):
        p = canvas.Canvas(response)
        p.drawString(10, 800, ' '+ pytanie[i].title)        


    qrw = QrCodeWidget('a') 
    b = qrw.getBounds()

    w=b[2]-b[0] 
    h=b[3]-b[1] 

    d = Drawing(200,200,transform=[200./w,0,0,200./h,0,0]) 
    d.add(qrw)

    renderPDF.draw(d, p, 1, 1)

    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You should just loop over Pytanie.objects.all():
2. Put the initialization of p outside the loop

   ```
   p = canvas.Canvas(response)
   for pytanie in Pytanie.objects.all():        
       p.drawString(10, 800, ' '+ pytanie.title)
   ```

Comment: I still get only the last question in my pdf :(

Comment: ah, i see now, you constantly reinitialize p

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change coordinates of the string:

```
p = canvas.Canvas(response)
for i, pytanie in enumerate(Pytanie.objects.all()):
    p.drawString(10, 800 + i*10, ' '+ pytanie.title)
```